# How to Trigger an action on SharePoint online sub site creation?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

**I need to achieve the following functionality:**

When a user create a project using MPP then a sub site is created automatically in root site collection in SharePoint Online. This is taken care by Microsoft.

Here our requirement is need to copy the default documents in documents library automatically, when a project sub site is created.

I verify MS flows, Designer workflows and Remote event receivers. I dint find trigger point in those.

With designer workflows will trigger site creation action but this workflow having manual action only.

We need a trigger action on a sub site is creation in root site collection in SharePoint Online root site collection.

So can you please provide is there any better approach is available.

Comment: you can create a custom list in the root site collection where you will store NewSiteName/NewSiteID when a new site is create. Then, this will trigger the second part.

Comment: @Ahmed Bouchaala, thanks for your comment. How we can store in a list NewSiteName/NewSiteID when new site is created automatically.

Comment: The same automation that create the web will create the list ite. But i think Lee_MSFT has a better solution. if that work it will be better

Answer (score 1):

For add-in solution, there is `WebProvisioned` event which occurs after a new site has been created.

You could check [this thread](https://saidivesh.wordpress.com/2015/10/31/remote-web-provisioned-event-receiver-sharepoint-2013-provider-hosted-app/) for sample solution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Lee_MSFT, I will try this once and let you know if i have any queries.