# Online - Notification when new team site is created or deleted

Tags: sharepoint-online, alert

I'm using SharePoint Online. Users are able to create their own sites or to create site with Microsoft Teams.

Is it possible to notify with an e-mail a specific user (or a group of users) when a new site is created? And is it possible to do the same when/if the site is deleted?

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, there are no triggers or settings for creating site in SharePoint.

I recommend that you trigger flow by clicking the create site button then send email to group or a specific user.

[SharePoint Online: Trigger a Microsoft Flow with button click](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52544.sharepoint-online-trigger-a-microsoft-flow-with-button-click.aspx)

Or you can refer to the following situation:

[How to Trigger an action on SharePoint online sub site creation?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/256681/how-to-trigger-an-action-on-sharepoint-online-sub-site-creation)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want to do something like **when a SharePoint site is created...**

I believe there is no trigger in Power Automate that will serve you.

You should look for a way how to trigger a ms flow when the button "Create Site" is clicked.